# Probability of consecutive heads

Tags: probability

We want to compute the probability of the following event :
"Getting two consecutive heads in 25 coin tosses".

What I did is the following : There are $2^{25}$ possible outcomes for the coin tosses that can be written as sequences $(a_1,\cdots,a_{25})$ with $a_i \in \{H,T\}$. The sequences that satisfy our events are the ones like $(H,H,...)$ with $2^{23}$ possibilities for the "...". We do this 24 times for forms like $(\cdots,H,H,\cdots)$. That gives us a probability of $\frac{24\cdot2^{23}}{2^{25}}=6$. I realized this is false because I counted some sequences twice or more.

How can I do it properly (would like to avoid using inclusion-exclusion principle) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a different approach:

Let's compute the number of toss sequences with no $HH$.  Let $a_n$ be the number of such sequences of length $n$.  Clearly $a_1=2,a_2=3$.

Now, any such sequence of length $≥2$ must end in one of $T$ or $TH$.  Hence $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$ for $n≥3$

It follows that the $a_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers,  and that $a_{20}$ is $17711$.

Note:  the $a_n$ have a different indexing than the usual Fibonacci numbers.  Indeed, $a_n=F_{n+1}$.

Thus the number of sequences of length $20$ which do contain an $HH$ is $$2^{20}-17711=1030865$$

Since all sequences have the same probability (namely $\frac 1{2^{20}}$) the answer is $$\frac {1030865}{2^{20}}\approx  .983$$

Note:  on review I see the problem asked about $25$, not $20$.  Of course the same procedure works and we get $$\frac {2^{25}-a_{25}}{2^{25}}\approx .994$$

Comment: Did you mean $a_1=2,a_2=3$?

Comment: I think @DanielMathias is right — the number of sequences is $a_n = F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the (zero-indexed) Fibonacci sequence. In addition, you could define $a_0 = F_1 = 1$, since there is one possible sequence of zero tosses and it has no repeated heads in it.  Nice argument otherwise, though — I was writing up a similar solution when you posted yours, and this one's more elegant than mine was.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Ah, I did not mean to suggest that the $a_n$ were the Fibonacci numbers *with the usual indexing*.   Of course there is a shift.  I will edit to reflect that.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMathias  Absolutely, thanks.

Comment: I think the shift is 2 not just 1 as the sequence starts with 1 1 2 3

Comment: @ArnaudMégret:  I was assuming the "zero-indexed" Fibonacci sequence, i.e., $F_0 = 1$, $F_1 = 1$, $F_2 = 2$, etc.  This is also sometimes called the "combinatorial" convention;  see [here for further discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451170/in-the-fibonacci-sequence-is-fib0-0-or-1/29337929)

Comment: +1, beat me to it.  Beyond that, I think that in a problem like this, recursion is typically a much easier approach  than either the direct approach or Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: +1 Nice and unbeatable! Comparing with mine we see a meeting of Fibonacci and Pascal.

Comment: @user2661923 and it also beats stars and bars (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where it's easier to work out the probability that the event *doesn't* happen.

Hint: if you don't get two heads in a row, that means every head is followed by a tail.

Comment: Perfect, there are only two sequences with no consecutive tails or heads. Thank you !

Comment: ... and so the answer is....?

Comment: You can have consecutive tails.

Comment: The probability of getting two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails is $1-\frac{2}{2^{25}}$ right. Intuitively I would divide this result by $2$ to get the final probability @DavidG.Stork

Comment: No no no.  Your events are not independent.  If you get a double head on slot 1 and slot 2, that will affect your probability of getting a double head on slot 2 and slot 3.  See?  Try on a simple problem:  n=4.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes I do. That's why I thought of using inclusion exclusion formula but I really don't like it.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to do *SOMETHING* if you want to actually solve this problem, because as far as I see it your "answer" is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to consider two series of numbers :

$R^T_n$ : the numbers of the n first draws that have no consecutive heads and are terminated by a tail

$R^H_n$ : the number of the n first draws that have no consecutive heads and are terminated by a head

you have $R^T_1= R^H_1 = 1$

Then the recursive equations :
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
        R^T_{n+1}= R^H_n + R^T_n \\
        R^H_{n+1}= R^T_n
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

This is closely related to the recursive sequence of the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$. Actually, $R^T_n=F_{n+1}$ and $R^H_n=F_n$

We can use the closed-form of $F_n=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}}{\sqrt5}$ but you can find tables on the Internet.

So $P = 1- \frac{F_{25}+F_{26}}{2^{25}} = 1- \frac{196418}{3355432}\sim 1-0.005853713$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to find the number of strings of length $25$ containing e.g. $3$ times character $H$ and $22$ times character $T$ and *not* containing $HH$ as substring.

We can start with a string $HTHTH$ in the understanding that then character $T$ must be added $20$ times.

This boils down to writing $20$ as a sum of $4$ nonnegative integers an applying stars and bars we find $\binom{23}3$ possibilities.

Above we did it for $n=3$ characters $H$ and $25-n=22$ characters $T$ but of course we can do that for every integer $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots,13\}$ finding $\binom{26-n}n$ possibilities.

This proves that the probability of getting no consecutive heads by $25$ coin tosses equals:
$$2^{-25}\sum_{n=0}^{13}\binom{26-n}n$$Then the probability of getting at least $2$ consecutive heads equals:$$1-2^{-25}\sum_{n=0}^{13}\binom{26-n}n$$

I vaguely suspect the summation also equals the $14$-th Fibonaccinumber so that we can write the probability as:$$1-2^{-25}F_{14}$$but now it's time to go to bed. Tomorrow I will have a second look.

---

**Edit**

Unfortunately I made a counting mistake (@#&*). The summation does not equal $F_{14}$ but $F_{26}=196418$.

The probability is:$$1-2^{-25}F_{26}=1-\frac{196418}{33554432}=\frac{33358014}{33554432}\approx0.994146$$

This answer agrees with the nice answer of @lulu.

For completeness: in my answer the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) start with: $F_0=F_1=1$.

Comment: See [lulu's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262002/248639) to see where the Fibonacci connection comes from.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you. Yes, at the moment that I published my last review I saw the nice answer of lulu. I postponed to have a good look (too late, time to go to bed) but the word 'Fibonacci' in it had reached me. I remembered vaguely that I saw something like that before. It is labeled in my brain as: "Fibonacci shows up in Pascal".